# Is it possible to run xvfb on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, xvfb

I'd like to run xvfb on Heroku. On my mac, I used the dmg to install it. Would anyone have any idea how to go about this on Heroku?

I came across these buildpacks (http://github.com/douglasjsellers/heroku-xvfb-buildpack) - but following the instructions didn't seem to solve the problem as xvfb is still not installed properly. Also, I tried installing the xvfbwrapper (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xvfbwrapper/0.1.0), but it's still not working on Heroku (apologies for what is potentially a noob question).

Here is the error I get in my logs off of Heroku:

```
2015-02-24T02:09:16.035298+00:00 app[web.6]: cmd=['Xvfb', '-help']
2015-02-24T02:09:16.035564+00:00 app[web.6]: Program install error! 
2015-02-24T02:09:16.035302+00:00 app[web.6]: OSError=[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Here is the code:

```
temp = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix='.html')
html = os.fdopen(temp[0], "r+")
html.write(cv)
html.seek(0, 0)

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

# Open the file on Selenium to load the JavaScript
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("file://" + temp[1])
```

Comment: I'm stuck too. Yesterday I got it working on amazon quite easily, but it just won't budge on heroku.

Answer (score 7):

I found this question while researching how to update Xvfb for Cedar-14, and I managed to get #2 to work. So here's how:

1. I used buildpack-apt to install `x11-xkb-utils xvfb x11-xkb-utils xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-scalable xfonts-cyrillic libxfont1 xvfb`.
2. After running the apt buildpack, you need to patch Xvfb a bit to make everything work smoothly. For that, I used my own [run-bash buildpack](https://github.com/fxtentacle/heroku-buildpack-runbash#master), but everything that lets you run a bash script during Heroku compile will work. Here's the script I used to patch Xvfb and index the fonts: https://gist.github.com/fxtentacle/960cdb96ece01add8686
3. Now you can use `heroku run bash` to check with `XAUTHORITY=/tmp/xvfb-run.2NG0xl/Xauthority Xvfb ":99" -screen 0 1280x1024x24 -nolisten tcp` that the Xvfb is working.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible, but complicated. I followed some of what fxtentacle did (in their answer), but this may be simpler. These instructions provide for a minimal Xvfb setup; it still prints out a bunch of warnings.

Use [heroku-buildpack-apt](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-apt) to install the `xvfb` and `libnotify4` debian packages. Then use this buildpack to fix the `/usr/bin/xkbcomp` issue:
https://github.com/captain401/heroku-buildpack-xvfb

Then you can use `xvfb-run $PROGRAM` to run your application.

Comment: Using above instruction I was able to run xvfb-run. Unfortunately electron fails with: `error while loading shared libraries: libnotify.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

Running it manually via `bash` didn't give any error. libnotify4 _is_ installed -- under `/app/.apt`. I wonder why node process didn't pick up `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` env var.

Comment: Ah, this changed sometime in the last month - did you install libnotify4 via the Aptfile for heroku-buildpack-apt? I also had to add it (in addition to xvfb). You can check your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` by running `heroku run bash` to get a shell.

Comment: Yeah, I installed via Aptfile. Invoking electron with `xvfb-run` on bash did not give me any issue. However, doing it via a nodejs process never worked for me :(. I even tried to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` from Heroku config, no luck -- it's `libnotify4` issue again.

Comment: Electron has other issues too - this is fixed in a very recent release: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=522853

Answer (score 2):

I'm wondering the same thing.  Seems like you already found [this guy's issue](https://discussion.heroku.com/t/trying-to-run-xvfb-in-heroku-fails-with-buildpacks/788).  All the buildpacks mentioned are 1+ years old, and don't work anymore.

Two viable seeming options:

1. Compile a self-contained xvfb binary a la https://github.com/kenshin23/xvfb-portable-binary that runs on Heroku's current OS and architecture, rebuild when they update.
2. Install all dependencies from the apt package manager into someplace like ~/.apt, and run from there, as in the latest [buildpack-apt](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-apt/blob/master/bin/compile).  For me, this option dies with `sh: 1: /usr/bin/xkbcomp: not found`.  Xvfb is looking in `/`, while apt installed the command to `~/.apt/usr/bin/xkbcomp`.  Haven't figured out how to tell Xvfb to look in `~/.apt/`.