# Heroku: xvfb buildpacks not installed

Tags: heroku, xvfb, buildpack

Hi StackOverflow community,

I want to use xvfb buildpack in heroku.
However, I always get the error in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28687120/is-it-possible-to-run-xvfb-on-heroku).

I have a list of buildpacks added in heroku:
 * heroku/php
 * heroku/python
 * https:// github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt
 * https:// elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/captain401/heroku-buildpack-xvfb

```
$ heroku buildpacks:add heroku/php
$ heroku buildpacks:add heroku/python
$ heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt
$ heroku buildpacks:add https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/captain401/heroku-buildpack-xvfb
$ git push heroku master
Everything is up to date

$ heroku logs --tail
   app[web.1]: cmd=['Xvfb','-help']
   app[web.1]:     ubuntu_package=PACKAGE).check_installed()
   app[web.1]: Program install error!
   app[web.1]:   __init__.py", line 180, in check_installed
   app[web.1]:     raise EasyProcessCheckInstalledError(self)
   app[web.1]: [2017-05-15 03:31:42] app.DEBUG: < 200 [] []
   app[web.1]: OSError=[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What seems to be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made things work using https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt.

Specifically running:

```
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt
```